# Primary and Secondary DNS for a Subdomain

Tags: dns, ip, a-records

I need to assign a secondary IP for a subdomain to redirect into. This is in case a first IP is not working.

Does creating multiple A records with the same name allow the browser to cycle through them in case one of them is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple A records associated with a domain are in fact the basis of **DNS round robin** load balancing.

However, do not confuse this with **automatic failover**. If one of the IP addresses is not working, then the browser(which is a client) *would not automatically retry the others*.

So which IP would a browser use? Well, the nameservers return the A records in different order at different times, to a querying client. Typically, the client just uses the first A record value that it gets. Further, the client would not query again until the TTL expires for that A record. All this querying of the nameservers, and caching until TTL is managed by a component called stub resolver, which works on request from browser.